# Accessing Sort column AND direction

Tags: jquery

I have a nice jQuery datatable happening with sortable columns.  A request came in to capture 1) The column that was clicked on and 2) the sort direction at the time of the click.  I've looped through various sort related objects in the datatables object but cannot seem to get those two singular values.

For the purpose of this question, I would like the end result to be something like alert('You clicked the column ' + column) and alert('The sort direction when you clicked was ' + sort direction).

How do I accomplish this?  As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, essentially you only need **1** specific piece of information to accomplish this: The initial location of the row (that the user is sorting) in the table.

There's different ways to get that, but likely the easiest way is to simply set a data attribute for each row to hold that row's initial location when you generate the table.

Example:

```
$.each($YOURTABLE.children(), function(idx, val) { val.data('position', idx);});
```

Now, all you need to do is on the **sortstop** event, grab that value and compare it to that row's new location:

```
$YOURTABLE.bind('sortstop', function(event, ui) {
    //$(ui.item[0]) selects the user-selected row
    var oldPosition = $(ui.item[0]).data('position'),
        newPosition;    

    //get row's new position
    $.each($YOURTABLE.children(), function(idx, val) {
        if($(val) === $(ui.item[0]))
            newPosition = idx; //store new position
    }
    //now compare
    if(oldPosition > newPosition)
        ////alert user row (oldPosition) moved up
    else if(oldPosition < newPosition)
        ////alert user row (oldPosition) moved down

    //refresh all row positions using first code example
}
```

});

Hopefully that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Adamb, That's sounds like something that might work.  However, It doesn't seem like this code is being recognized.  I googled 'sortstop' and didn't come up with anything.

Comment: There are multiple ways to hook into the sortable "stop" event. "sortstop" is the event's name when using the .bind() function. I would recommend looking into the _jQuery Sortable API_ docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop. Also, here's a more direct example of what you're likely looking for: [FOLLOW LINK HERE](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/jquery-sortable-getting-the-new-and-original-index). If helpful please mark so :)